# Form of $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ satisfying $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2,k_1,k_2)=\mathbb{C}(u,v)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, birational-geometry, involutions, transcendence-degree

Let $\beta$ be an involution on $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, namely, $\beta$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra automorphism of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ of order two.
Denote the set of symmetric elements with respect to $\beta$ by $S_{\beta}$ and the set of skew-symmetric elements w.r.t. $\beta$ by $K_{\beta}$.

Let $s_1,s_2 \in S_{\beta}$ and $k_1,k_2 \in K_{\beta}$.
Assume that every two of $\{s_1,s_2,k_1,k_2\}$ are algebraically independent over $\mathbb{C}$.
Then $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2,k_1,k_2)$ has transcendence degree two over $\mathbb{C}$.

By a known result from algebraic geometry (which appears [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540914/a-pure-algebraic-proof-for-any-unirational-surface-over-mathbbc-is-rationa)), there exist $u,v \in \mathbb{C}(x,y)$
such that $\mathbb{C}(s_1,s_2,k_1,k_2)=\mathbb{C}(u,v)$.

Assume, for simplicity, that $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ (perhaps it is possible to find such $u,v$, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3567214/concerning-k-subset-l-subset-kx-y) question).

Call Property P the following property: There exist an automorphism $g$ of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$
such that $g(u),g(v) \in S_{\beta} \cup K_{\beta}$.

> Could one find a (counter)example in which property P is not satisfied? Or a proof that property P is satisfied?

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838672/realizing-subring-as-ring-of-invariants) question seems slightly relevant (perhaps we should assume that some  field extension here is Galois?).

Thank you very much!